# PHP database sessions creating multiple records for same session ID

Tags: php, session, cakephp, mongodb, session-cookies

So I have this weird problem where PHP sessions are saving to the database (MongoDB) multiple times, all with the same ID. The first record has the correct session data, while the second has the wrong session data. This is causing my sessions to fail immediately on the next page (or next AJAX call) since it's grabbing the latest record.

Here is my session ini settings:

```
array(
'session.auto_start' => '0',
'session.bug_compat_42' => '',
'session.bug_compat_warn' => '',
'session.cache_expire' => '180',
'session.cache_limiter' => 'must-revalidate',
'session.cookie_domain' => '',
'session.cookie_httponly' => '1',
'session.cookie_lifetime' => '0',
'session.cookie_path' => '/',
'session.cookie_secure' => '1',
'session.entropy_file' => '',
'session.entropy_length' => '0',
'session.gc_divisor' => '1000',
'session.gc_maxlifetime' => '14400',
'session.gc_probability' => '1',
'session.hash_bits_per_character' => '5',
'session.hash_function' => '0',
'session.name' => 'Game',
'session.referer_check' => '',
'session.save_handler' => 'user',
'session.save_path' => '/var/lib/php/session',
'session.serialize_handler' => 'php',
'session.use_cookies' => '1',
'session.use_only_cookies' => '1',
'session.use_trans_sid' => '0'
)
```

And my CakePHP settings:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
'cookie' => PROJECT,
'checkAgent' => false,
'autoRegenerate' => false, // We don't want it to regenerate
'defaults' => 'database',
'handler' => array(
    'engine' => 'DatabaseSession',
    'model' => 'Session'
),
'ini' => array(
    'session.cookie_lifetime' => 0, // Until the browser is closed
    'session.cookie_httponly' => true,
    'session.referer_check' => '',
    'session.cache_limiter' => 'nocache'
),
));
```

And heres an example of multiple record in the database (notice they have the same ID but different content):

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5011b8c9564d444d04000083"), "id" : "mnor9aspiacp3g41qq8g0fotk2", "data" : "Config|a:3:{s:9:\"userAgent\";s:0:\"\";s:4:\"time\";i:1343353096;s:9:\"countdown\";i:10;}fb_466806330012492_code|s:74:\"2.AQC3yKQXi2e-6_VjI.3600.1343343600.1-672639577|pkfXkSypomU_3RY2-xM3A93rGrVo\";fb_4668063X30012492_access_token|s:110:\"AAAGojtF6Xs0wBAIoUwOoMU3WIt4ZBAih0NUvwtGePBxYv6oOT1QvbEZAb77j2h8ZBXKnpHrXktxHmz1WXCyr5VR9RwdaiGzrxfNRgEPr06gAZDZD\";fb_466806330012492_user_id|s:9:\"xxxx\";Game|a:6:{s:7:\"user_id\";s:24:\"4ff60631ec0f92c5690002a6\";s:9:\"player_id\";s:24:\"4ff60631ec0f92c5690002a7\";s:7:\"game_id\";s:24:\"5009ce57d09b3efe03000000\";s:11:\"facebook_id\";s:9:\"xxx\";s:11:\"accessToken\";s:110:\"AAAGoXjtF6s0wBAIoUwOoMXU3WIt4ZBAih0NUvwXtGePBxYv6oOT1QvbEZAb77j2h8ZBKnpHrXktxHmz1WCyr5VR9RwdaiGzrxfNRgEXPr06gAZDZD\";s:5:\"round\";i:1;}", "expires" : NumberLong(1343338697), "modified" : ISODate("2012-07-26T21:38:17.083Z"), "created" : ISODate("2012-07-26T21:38:17.083Z") }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5011b8ca564d445c0400008f"), "id" : "mnor9aspiacp3g41qq8g0fotk2", "data" : "Config|a:3:{s:9:\"userAgent\";s:0:\"\";s:4:\"time\";i:1343353098;s:9:\"countdown\";i:10;}", "expires" : NumberLong(1343338698), "modified" : ISODate("2012-07-26T21:38:18.689Z"), "created" : ISODate("2012-07-26T21:38:18.689Z") }
```

I can't seem to figure out this problem. I tried switching to memcache storage, but the same thing happens. A few more things to note:

- The site is using HTTPS
- I am using the Facebook API which adds to the session, however I am creating the app session first
- The cookie with the session ID does exist and is being passed in all headers for every request
- I am running on Amazon EC2

I am running out of ideas here as my ini settings look correct, and I've placed debug statements all through the app to ensure the order of operations is correct. Everything looks good so far.

Comment: It seems like CakePHP's session cache handlers cause the same problem, but if I use the built in PHP session.save_handler = memcache approach, the problem fixes itself.

I will proceed as if this is a problem in Cakeland.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that the MongoDB session adapter for CakePHP doesn't store the session ID as the `_id` field (which need not always be an ObjectId)?

Comment: Are you running single ec2 instance or a few instances in an autoscaling group caster? I have similar problem and I have 2 identical instances.

Answer (score 0):

On the mongodb side, you can use ensureIndex({id: 1}, {unique: true}) to prevent the insert from happening.